# Maven Project is not opening in jProfiler?

Tags: jprofiler

I am not able to understand that why my maven packages are  not showing in j profiler?
when i am running it as a local virtual machine it shows me like this :

```
JProfiler> Protocol version 39  
JProfiler> Using JVMTI  
JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.  
JProfiler> 64-bit library  
JProfiler> Listening on port: 33211.    
JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.  
JProfiler> Can retransform classes.  
JProfiler> Can retransform any class.   
JProfiler> Native library initialized  
JProfiler> VM initialized  
JProfiler> Waiting for a connection from the JProfiler GUI ...  
JProfiler> Using dynamic instrumentation  
JProfiler> Time measurement: elapsed time  
JProfiler> CPU profiling enabled
```

please help me 
 i am stuck in it .
thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "my maven packages"?

Comment: like i have my own prject which is imported in eclipse???

Comment: do you have any idea???

Comment: plz help me i m totally stuck in it....